# Do I need to create variable using if statement in SAS?

Tags: sql, if-statement, sas

I need to write a code in SAS in order to substitute Access. There's one part of this code that I don't know how to do it due to the difference between Access/SQL and SAS using "if".

While in Access the command "if" doesn't need to create a new variable, in SAS we have to create it.

In Access, the code is something like this:

```
(IIf(date2 > par_final, par_final, date2) - 
IIf(date1 > par_initial, par_initial, date1))/365 as exposure
```

All the variables are in date format. When I write this in SAS code, I have to create a new variable. For example:

```
If date2 > par_final then 
        Field1 = par_final; Else Field1 = date2;
```

However, I want to create Just the exposure. I don't need to create any other variables.

How can I write this in SAS code?

I thought firstly create the first variable using the if condition and also the Second variable using if after minus. Then I make (field1 - field2)/365 to create exposure and drop field1 and field2.

Could anyone give me a better suggestion? Are there ways to do it without creating those variables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does it matter whether or not you make a new variable? If you don't want the variable written to the output dataset then use a DROP statement.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a way that can solve the problem in just one step. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Is your code in a `data` step or `proc sql`? Please post fuller code block and not line snippets. Feel free to even post the fuller Access query so we can understand context.

Answer (score 2):

One of the [divergences](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) of MS Access' SQL dialect from standard SQL is [`IIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) function (not to be confused with `IF` operator) which most database dialects use the `CASE` statement.

```sql
(IIf(date2 > par_final, par_final, date2) - 
 IIf(date1 > par_initial, par_initial, date1))/365 as exposure
```

Therefore, above can be translated with [**`CASE`**](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=n0a85s0ijz65irn1h3jtariooea5.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) expressions and should run in any compliant ANSI-92 SQL compiler including SAS's `proc sql`:

```sql
(CASE WHEN date2 > par_final   THEN par_final   ELSE date2 END - 
 CASE WHEN date1 > par_initial THEN par_initial ELSE date1 END) / 365 AS exposure
```

Answer (score 1):

SAS has conditional logic functions `IFC` and `IFN` that return respectively a character or numeric value based on a logical evaluation.  SAS date values are serial integers from epoch `01-JAN-1960` so you can continue to use subtraction to compute number of days of exposure.

Try replacing

```
(IIf(date2 > par_final, par_final, date2) - 
IIf(date1 > par_initial, par_initial, date1))/365 as exposure
```

with

```
( IFN(date2 > par_final, par_final, date2) 
  - 
  IFN(date1 > par_initial, par_initial, date1)
) / 365 as exposure label="Years of exposure"
```

**Examples**

```
data have;
input ini d1 d2 fin;
datalines;
1 2 3 4
2 1 3 4
1 2 4 3
2 1 4 3
;


* Expression in SQL;

proc sql;
  create table foo as 
  select
    ( ifn ( d2 > fin, fin, d2 )
      - 
      ifn ( d1 > ini, ini, d1 )
    )
  as diff label = 'Difference of IFNs'
  from have
  ;
quit;

* Expression in DATA Step;

data foo_also;
  set have;

  diff = ( ifn ( d2 > fin, fin, d2 )
           - 
           ifn ( d1 > ini, ini, d1 )
         );

  attrib diff label='Difference of IFNs';
run;
```

**Also**

Try using function `MIN` instead of `IFN`

```
   exposure = (min(d2,fin) - min(d1,ini)) / 365;
```

Comment: I've tried to use IFN but code reject the use of "(" before the first "IFN". Thank you for trying to help me. I solved the problem using creating exposure and then I dropped field1 and field2 as I said before.

Comment: Without seeing all the code I would say you might have tried to use SQL select syntax as DATA Step assignment statement.